# How to live broadcast from my webcam to my website with pure HTML5 in 2019?

Tags: html, video, http-live-streaming

How can I use HTML5 and the MediaSource API to stream live video and audio from my webcam to my website?

It seems MPEG DASH is not supported anymore... https://caniuse.com/#search=DASH

And HLS doesn't look good either... https://caniuse.com/#search=HLS

Is there really no way to do this even with modern browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MPEG DASH is not supported anymore

Yes it is, you just need player software to parse the manifest and download the media. See video.js/dash.js

> And HLS doesn't look good either

Yes it does, you just need player software to parse the manifest and download the media. See video.js/hls.js